# How to uninstall Toribash?

Tags: uninstall

I installed [Toribash](http://www.toribash.com/), but now I want to uninstall it. Unfortunately, it doesn't come with an uninstaller, so I've got no clue how to do it.

I read somewhere all I need is to delete the files and remove a registry entry, but I'm not sure. Its installer might polluted other areas of the system. It's very hard to track down some registry entries. Any reliable method?

---

Edit: It doesn't pollute the filesystem, but creates a large number of registry entries. (For example it associates `*.rpl` files with itself.)

Comment: The registry isn't a huge problem, really. And why would you uninstall toribash :(

Comment: @Phoshi: Those eegistry entries can cause some hard-to-track-down problems.

Comment: Problems like what? I'm somehow doubtful that it's anything serious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like Toribash doesn't create files outside its directory. Fortunately it doesn't make any new registry entry besides its association with its replay files.

So it's enough to delete its files, shortcuts and remove the association of the `*.rpl` files.

Comment: I used to work with Toribash, and I can confirm this. Loads of `.rpl` files (replays) and `.tif` files (head textures), but they all reside in the main directory (or its subdirectories). As of version 3.0 or thereabouts, Toribash didn't use the registry at all, and I don't see any reason why it would do this now.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you really want to, you could try installing it again, and if it displays a list of files it installs, then you could use that to make sure all traces are gone. But, since it doesn't look like a piece of spyware, you could also just delete the folder/start menu link and be done with it.

Comment: Files aren't the main problem. I'm worried about registry entries. However, I give it a shot, maybe it lists something. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't list anything during the install.

Answer (score 0):

Windows? Try [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/). Very good at uninstalling and clearing out registry entries. Afterwards use [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) to check for any remaining files and folders.

Comment: Revo can't uninstall it. At least I couldn't find a way.
Fortunately, it doesn't pollute the filesystem so there's no need for Everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows 8,

1. Go to the main menu where you see the tiles of apps.
2. Put your mouse in the bottom right corner. A side menu will pop up.
3. Click search.
4. Search *to* then click Toribash (**do not open the file**) then click once; it should highlight.
5. Go to the bottom, then press “open file location”. Remember, you must have already deleted Toribash out of the Recycling Bin.
6. Click “open file location” and right-click the file “Toribash”, then press delete.

There you go. You’re welcome, Windows 8 users.

Comment: "Remember, you must have already deleted Toribash out of the Recycling Bin." I don't know what this means. If it's something you should have *already* done, why doesn't it appear earlier in the list of things to do?